# Column chart in Highcharts - select series with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, charts, highcharts

I am using **Highcharts** in **rCharts** to make an interactive column chart. My data is divided into 40ish groups so I naturally got rid of the legend. However, I would still like to keep the functionality of selecting specific series by either clicking on the column and selecting that series or alternatively by hovering over the column and dimming all the other series, or both. My code so far is below. I have successfully added the click to select option but I have failed to add the select series functionality.

```
h1 <- hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", group = "group", data = data, type = "column")
h1$legend(enabled=FALSE)
h1$chart(height=700, width=700)
h1$title(text = "Title")
h1$subtitle(text = "Subtitle")
h1$yAxis(title = list(text = "yAxis"))
h1$xAxis(title = list(text = "xAxis"))
h1$tooltip(formatter = "#! function(){return('<b>x: </b>' + this.x + '<br/>' +
       '<b>y: </b>' + this.series.name + '<br/>' +
       '<b>z: </b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(100*this.y,2)) + 
       '<b>%</b>';} !#")
h1$plotOptions(series = list(allowPointSelect = 'true'))
```

Here is an example interactive plot http://tmp.ocpu.io/x0b4763059b/files/output.html
So instead of clicking on the legend to toggle series on/off I would like to click/hover on the columns to toggle/brighten that specific series.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. Added:

```
h1$plotOptions(
  series = list( 
    point = list(
      events = list(
        click = "#! function() {
          if (chart.series[0].visible) {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
              chart.series[i].hide();
            }
            this.series.show();
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
              chart.series[i].show();
            }
          }
        } !#"))
    )
)
```

and removed:

```
h1$plotOptions(series = list(allowPointSelect = 'true'))
```